# Is there anyway we can observe changes in Objecbox database like we observe for CRUD operations in Room Database?

Tags: android, kotlin, objectbox

I was building an app on Jetpack Compose and saved some data using Objexbox, CRUD operations work fine, but I have a problem here. Is there any way we can observe the changes in the data in the object box as we observe in Room using Livedata.

Cause when I add or update the data on one screen and navigate back to the Listing Screen(Screen where all the saved data are listed) the update or added data is not reflected in the UI immediately. I have to return back to the main screen and go to the Listing Screen again to see the changes in Jetpack Compose.

`

```
class EntityObserver() : DataObserver<Feed> {

    override fun onData(data: Feed) {

    }

}`
```

I tried extending DataObserver but nothing really worked out. Is there anyone who could help me with this?

Comment: You can use ``.distinctUntilChanged()``

``val distinct = YOUR_VIEW_MODEL.YOUR_OBSERVER.distinctUntilChanged() // Use .distinctUntilChanged()
        distinct.observe(this){
            // Your data
        }``